# Кол-во подписчиков страницы ВК

Tags: vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Подскажите пожалуйста, как на данный момент вывести количество подписчиков личной страницы ВК на страницу сайта. Нужно вывести просто число. Все описанные методы через поиск устарели. C API ВК я не дружу. Ковырялся так и не понял. Спасибо заранее!

Answer (score 0):

Получить количество подписчиков можно через метод [users.get](https://vk.com/dev/users.get?params[user_ids]=2050&params[fields]=counters&params[name_case]=Nom&params[v]=5.107) с аргументом `fields=counters` и `user_ids={id пользователя в вк или короткое имя}`

Если вы не знаете id пользователя но знаете ссылку на страницу, то можно указывать которое имя.

Например для этих ссылок

- vk.com/id2050
- vk.com/me

в `user_ids` можно указать `me` или `id2050` или просто id `2050` результат будет одинаковый.

[image: результат вызова users.get]

Чтобы [вызвать метод API ВКонтакте](https://vk.com/dev/api_requests) вам надо [создать приложение](https://vk.com/editapp?act=create) и использовать его сервисный токен

Comment: Иван, а как это все в php файле вывести?

Comment: Пытаюсь вот так. Ничего не выводит.

<?php
$user_ids = мой_ид;
$request_params = array(
'user_id' => $user_ids,
'fields' => 'counters',
'v' => '5.52',
'access_token' => 'Ключ
);
$get_params = http_build_query($request_params);
$result = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?'. $get_params));
echo($result -> response[0] -> followers);
?>

Comment: echo($result->response[0]->counters->followers); `->counters` пропустили

Answer (score 0):

Добился чего хотел. 
Вот правильный код:

```
    <?php
$user_ids = МОЙ_ID_ВК;
$request_params = array(
'user_id' => $user_ids,
'fields' => 'followers_count',
'v' => '5.110',
'access_token' => 'Сервисный_ключ_доступа_приложения'
);
$get_params = http_build_query($request_params);
$result = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?'. $get_params));
echo($result -> response[0] -> followers_count);
?>
```